# MS ACCESS Pivot Chart - Object Variable or With Block variable not set

Tags: ms-access

I am attempting to create a pivot table using VBA from MS Access. I have been able to create the pivot chart, but have not been able to add data fields due to error '91' Object variable or With block variable not set. I believe this is due to how I am setting the ObjActiveChrt.

Please see me code below:

```
Option Explicit       

     Sub SendEmailXLS()
     Dim appExcel As Excel.Application
     Dim objActiveWkb As Object
     Dim ActiveWorkbook As Object
     Dim objActiveChrt As Object

    Set objActiveWkb = appExcel.Application.ActiveWorkbook
    Set objActiveChrt = appExcel.Application.ActiveChart
    With objActiveWkb


   appExcel.Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, 23).Select
   appExcel.Sheets.Add
   objActiveWkb.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=1, SourceData:= _
    "xxx!R1C1:R10C34", Version:=1 _
    ).CreatePivotTable TableDestination:="Sheet1!R1C1", TableName:= _
    "BDA Pivot Chart", DefaultVersion:=xlPivotTableVersion10
.Worksheets(1).Select
.Worksheets(1).Range("A1").Select
.Worksheets(1).Shapes.AddChart2(201, 51).Select
objActiveChrt.PivotLayout.PivotTable.AddDataField
objActiveChrt.PivotLayout. _
    PivotTable.PivotFields("Traffic"), "Sum of Traffic", xlAverage
```

Comment: *Welcome to [so]!*  Where are you getting this error? Also, it lookslike you included half a procedure.  Please see how to create a **[mcve]** and also [here is a checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/stack-overflow-question-checklist/) from the site's top user to help write the "perfect question".

Comment: Try with: `Set objActiveChrt = objActiveWkb.ActiveChart`.

Comment: If I use this method I am now getting the error: 'unable to get pivottables property of the worksheet class'

Comment: Gustav - Thank you. I have fixed the error and added .Worksheet(1).Range() for data source.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use an Excel.Application object before pointing to a reference of one.

You could use `New` or `CreateObject` to create a new instance, or you can use `GetObject` to get a reference to an existing instance. As you seem to expect a specific Worksheet in an open Workbook, you won't want to create a new instance, so try this:

```
Set appExcel = GetObject("NameOfYourWorkbook").Application
```